# ANDROID: Formatted text in ArrayList

Tags: android, text, arraylist, format

I have this code:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo()

{

HashMap<String, List<String>> Conteudo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> Areas_Processos = new ArrayList<>();

Areas_Processos.add("<>start of bold directive<>"+"4 - text four"+"end of bold directive<>");

...

}
```

The output is `<>start of bold directive<>4 - Text four <>end of bold directive<>`, showing the directives to format the texts.

My expectation is to have the text in bold format, like this:
"**4 - Text four**"

Any ideas?

Comment: @MD why don't you do it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use **bold** html tags, I haven't seen `<>start of bold directive<>` before. If you can/want to use `<b></b>` tags then you can use Android's `Html.fromHtml` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>This will be bold.</b> This will not"));
```